# Summation of a trigonometric series - $\frac{\sin n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

**Question:**
Find the sum of the series:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin1}{1}+\frac{\sin2}{2}+\frac{\sin3}{3}+...+\frac{\sin n}{n}$$

I have no clue how to find this. Obviously I can see the sum will be convergent as the denominator gets increasingly bigger while the numerator is bound between $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Not so obvious, in my opinion. For instance $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ is divergent. You might need a sharper argument.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Aha.... Well I guess intuition can be wrong sometimes.

Comment: Could you let us know where you have stumbled upon this problem? Knowing this might help us to find a solution which avoids tools too complicated for you.

Comment: @Wojowu Well... it's this problem for college entrances. So it should be solved using 12th grade knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative Hint: consider the Fourier series of the $2\pi$-periodic function that equals $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ over $(0,2\pi)$.

Yet another way is to use the limit case of the [Euler-Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula): since $\text{sinc}(x)$ is a very well-behaved even analytic function, we simply have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin n}{n}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx-\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: 'Very well-behaved even analytic function'? What does it mean for a function to be 'well-behaved'? xD 
And how would i go about solving that integral? It doesn't seem simple...

Comment: You may find many topics here on MSE showing that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$, it is a *very* well-known integral.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a step-by-step breakdown using the fact that $\sin x = \text{Im}(e^{ix})$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin k}{k}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\text{Im}(e^{ik})}{k}$$
$$=\text{Im}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{ik}}{k}\right) =\text{Im}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(e^i)^k}{k}\right)$$
Now recall that the Taylor Series for $-\log(1-x)$ is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}$
$$=\text{Im}(-\log(1-e^i))$$
$$=\text{Im}(\text{Arg}(1-e^i))$$
We now express $1-e^i$ as $1-\cos(1)-i\sin(1)$. Noting that $1-\cos(x) > 0 \;(\forall x \in \mathbb R)$ we can simply let $\text{Arg}(1-e^i) = \arctan\left(\frac{\sin(1)}{1-\cos(1)}\right) = \arctan\left(\cot(\frac{1}{2})\right)$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}(\pi - 1)}$$

Comment: Just asking: is the last series convergent at $e^i$?

Comment: @Chip a good question. The simplest answer is that the absolute value of $e^i = 1$, which is within the interval of convergence of the series, namely $|x| \leq 1$. Now, I've mostly self studied mathematics so I am sure there are a few caveats here (there always are with complex numbers) but I am unsure of them... nevertheless, I know the formula works here.

Comment: @Chip I found the following quote from a related post giving more justification: "Let's first observe that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty u^k/k=-\ln(1-u)$. If we're concerned about the convergence radius, we can always replace
$u$ with $ue^{-\epsilon}$ and let $\epsilon\rightarrow0$. The branch of $\ln$ we're using is the one defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$: i.e. $\ln(re^{i\theta})=\ln r+i\theta$ where $r>0$ and $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$"

Comment: many thanks! It helped.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sin n$ is the imaginary part of $e^{i n}$.

Comment: @user1952009 Uhhh... yeah. The funny thing is we never learnt this theorem? So I'm pretty sure there's got to be some other way to solve it?

Comment: Well this doesn't seem to be working for me. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Not sure I understand. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple application of [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula)

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\left(n\right) \over n} & =
-1 + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\sin\left(n\right) \over n}
\\[3mm] &=
-1 + \left[\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\left(x\right) \over x}\,{\rm d}x +
{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{x \to 0}{\sin\left(x\right) \over x} +
{\rm i}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin\left({\rm i}n\right)/\left({\rm i}n\right) -
 \sin\left(-{\rm i}n\right)/\left(-{\rm i}n\right)\over {\rm e}^{2\pi t} - 1}\,{\rm d}t\right]
\\[3mm] &= -1 + {\pi \over 2} + {1 \over 2} + 0 =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over 2}\left(\pi - 1\right)}
\end{align}