# $A_n =\sum \limits_{j=1}^n\frac{\sin j}{j}$ convergence, not using series convergence tests(Abel, Dirichlet etc)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Let $A_n =\sum \limits_{j=1}^n\frac{\sin j}{j}$. How can I prove that $A_n$ converges as $n$ approaches infinity?

I know that if we think of it as an infinite series, it can be proved by applying appropriate convergence tests(for example, Abel's convergence test(or Dirichlet test). But I want a proof not using convergence tests of an infinite series, and think of this as a 'sequence' $A_n$ instead of a 'series'.

I read [Proving that the sequence $F_{n}(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin{kx}}{k}$ is boundedly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is) and other answers related to this question, but most of them used convergence tests and I don't know about Riemann-Lebesgue lemma or Fourier series. Actually I am taking an elementary analysis course, and this is an exercise on the textbook's 'sequence' part, not 'series'.

Comment: The sequence is defined as a serie, I think every method will just be a reformulation of convergence tests in some way or using Riemann-Lebesgue lemma..

Comment: Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1788570/629362) count as "not using series"?

Comment: Try to prove it standing on your left leg, with your hands tied behind your back, if that's how you understand mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for all. I was able to modify a proof using convergence tests into something that uses sequences(especially, I proved that $A_n$ is a cauchy sequence).